# WP - custom post type pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, categories, custom-post-type

I want make loop in category.php with pagination. My loop looks like this:

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'blog',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
    'paged' => $paged
    ) );

    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); 
?>

<!-- start article -->

<!-- end article -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_template_part('pagination') ?>
```

and function:

```
function pagination()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'prev_text'    => __('<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>'),
        'next_text'    => __('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    ));
}
```

When i click on paginate link he send me to `site/?cat=9&paged=2` and this site is index, not my next page with posts. I have tried many ways and i don't know what is wrong...

Any suggestions?

PS. Do not wonder to why I have pagination as template_part :)

Answer (score 0):

It's complately work. I check it.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'blog','posts_per_page' => 2,'orderby'=> 'menu_order','paged'=>$paged));
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();the_title();endwhile;
```

For pagination i use your code on same page.

```
$big = 999999999;
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'prev_text'    => __(''),
        'next_text'    => __(''),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
));
```